# Vim interpretation of Unicode Private Use Areas and fallback fonts

Tags: unicode, font

If I download [this file](https://0x0.st/oPX2.txt) and open it with GVim, here is what I see:

[image]

Now put the cursor on the "2" of "29" (after "Received" and before "December") and press [`g8`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#g8).

This prints the character is encoded in hex: `EF98BA`.

In binary this is `1110 1111 1001 1000 1011 1010`.

According to [UTF8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding), the mask to obtain the code point would be as follows:

`1110 1111 1001 1000 1011 1010`

`1110 xxxx 10xx xxxx 10xx xxxx`

So the code point would be `1111 01 1000 11 1010`.

In hexadecimal this is `F63A`.

This code point falls inside the [Private Use Area (BMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) "that, by definition, will not be assigned characters by the Unicode Consortium".

So why does Vim display a "2"?

Also, why is the font of the "2" is different than the font used in the surrounding text?

Is this some kind of fallback font?

GVIM version: 8.2.4428

OS: Fedora Workstation 35

guifont: Liberation Mono 14

Comment: Can you tell us, which version of GVim on which platform you are using and what your `guifont` option is set to? With GVim 8.2.4488 on Windows 10 and DejaVu Sans Mono and Courier I only see empty rectangles for all digits.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer I have edited my post with the asked information

Comment: Might really be some kind of fallback font, but I don't know how Linux font engines work. With Liberation Mono on Windows 10 I see empty spaces instead of the digits, with Li**t**eration Mono NF (a clone with symbols for powerline in the Private Use Area) there are again empty rectangles.